# Python: error when importing Class defined via function type()

Tags: python-3.x, oop, typing

Trying to understand some source code, I run into an issue I cannot figure out.
I created a minimum example as follows.
I have a main file and a module, named `main_file.py` and `Problem.py`.

The main file contains a Class definition, as well as a function that returns another class via the `type(name, bases, dict)` function,

```
import numpy


class BoundMetaClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
            
        if isinstance(value, numpy.ndarray):
            _value = value   
    @property
    def g(self):
        return self.value 


def bound(value) -> BoundMetaClass:
    bctype = int
    formcls = type("Bound", (int,), {})
    return formcls(value)

# bound(3)
# the error persists even if a Bound class object is initiated

import Problem
```

the module I am trying to import looks life, fleshed out to the bare bones just to make the error visible

```
from typing import List

class Problem:
   

    def __init__(self, bcs: List[Bound]):  
        self.attr1 = True
        self.attr2 = False
```

now I save them in the same folder, run `python main_file.py`  an get the error

```
NameError: name 'Bound' is not defined
```

Should not the `Bound` Class have been defined by `type()` in `main_file.py`?

The same error is retrieved if I use

```
def __init__(self, bcs: List[BoundMetaClass]):
```

but surely `BoundMetaClass` have been defined.

Sorry if it is trivial, it is my first attempt to understand `type()`
or such stuff, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type function does create a type, but as the **type is declared within a function body, it is not available in the module's namespace**. This means you cannot import it into your `problem.py` module.

If you really wanted to use the type function in this way, you'd need to invoke the function at the module level:

```
class BoundMetaClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
            
        if isinstance(value, numpy.ndarray):
            _value = value   
    @property
    def g(self):
        return self.value 

Bound = type("Bound", (int,), {})

# In problem.py

from typing import List
from main_file import Bound
...
```

Comment: thank you that was helpful. So even if the Class is defined at module level, it still needs to be imported in the module. I thought the module was simply executed, interpreted after the main, and hence would automatically be aware of classes defined therein, at module level, whixh seems to be false!  I also missed what you explained about classes defined at function level. Thank you